# How to get last file that not contain specific string

Tags: c#, string, file

I know how to get the last file, this the code:

```
string pattern = "Log*.xml";
string directory = set. Path;
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
var file = (from f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern) orderby f.LastWriteTime descending select f).First();
```

My question is: How can I get the last file that **not** contain specific string? or in another words, how can I get the last file that not contain "This is temporally file" string?

Thank you!

Comment: in the filename or in the contents of file?

Comment: @NoOne: file contain, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from top of my head:

```
dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(pattern)
   .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
   .Where(f => DoesntContain(f, myText))
   .FirstOrDefault()
```

Now you are free to make `DoesntContain` as complex or simple as you want. Either use `File.ReadAllText` or something like:

```
bool DoesntContain(FileInfo fileInfo, string text) {
   using (StreamReader r = fileInfo.OpenText()) {
      var contents = r.ReadToEnd();
      return !contents.Contains(text);
   }
}
```

You can write the method as extension to get more natural syntax like `fi.DoesntContain(...)`

Additionally, I suggest using `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` if the directory can contain many files: there is no need to retrieve them all, if the first one will match.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
string pattern = "Log*.xml";
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
var filesThatContains = dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern).
                  Where(f=>File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, f.Name), 
                                 Encofing.UTF8).IndexOf(SEARCH_STRING)>=0);
```

Comment: I haven't `.IndexOf` after `Encofing.UTF8)`. Do you know why? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do something simpler for a start:

```
    public static string[] FileNamesExcluding(string path, string pattern, string textToExclude)
    {
        // Put all txt files in root directory into array.
        string[] allFilesMatchingPattern = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern); // <-- Case-insensitive

        return allFilesMatchingPattern.SkipWhile(a => a.Contains(textToExclude)).ToArray();
    }
```

To call this method you can do:

```
FileNamesExcluding(@"C:\", "*.sys", "config").Last();
```